# Loading one user control after another has loaded - ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a UserControl A that has to be loaded first and after that completes loading, I need to load a UserControl B.

I prefer to add both these user controls on the page at compile time (would like to avoid dynamic loading if possible).

- If I add user controls on the page at compile time and set visible to false for User Control B, does it still execute the B's code behind? I can then set the visibility to true after loading User Control A
- Should I be using events/delegates for notifying the completion of loading User Control A?

Comment: Why does Control A need to be loaded before Control B?  UserControls shouldn't be designed to interact with other UserControls unless they are nested controls or composite controls. Can you explain your design further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't load everything in the page event in control b, just put a method on control b to be called. Then add an event to control a which the page consumes, when the event is raised, call the load method on control b.

Edit: SampleCode

Ok so for example, create

- a ASPX page
- 2x user controls

Put both user controls into the aspx page.

```
    <cc:control1 runat="server" id="control_one" />
    <cc:control2 runat="server" id="control_two" />
```

Then in **control 1**, create a delegate and event.

```
    public delegate void MyCustomEvent (EventArgs args);
    public event MyCustomEvent MyEvent;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyEvent(e);
    }
```

So I have the event raised on page load. So you would have your logic in there thats required, when your done, calls MyEvent event.

In the page you want to add a handler for that event so when it's called you can do something with it.

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        control_one.MyEvent += new WebUserControl1.MyCustomEvent(control_one_MyEvent);
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    void control_one_MyEvent(EventArgs args)
    {
        control_two.MyCustomLoad();
    }
```

So when the page is initialized I add the event handler. In the event handler I call a custom method on the second control to load stuff.

Then in the second control I have:

```
    public void MyCustomLoad()
    {
        //Stuff only loaded when event is raised and calls this method.
    }
```

So this allows control 1 to load something, say it's done, when the page knows it's done, it can tell control 2 to do something.

Edit: After discussing this with a friend I'll explain what I mean by controlling the order.

You cannot control the order of page-life-cycle events. i.e: You can't have Control A, run through all it's page-life-cycle events, then once it's done, have Control B run through all it's page-life-cycle events.

If you do-away with the page life cycle, you can do a degree, as my example above shows, create a way of controlling the order in which the controls are rendered. By raising an event(s) at certain points when Control A is finished, you can tell Control B to do something.

The intermediate between the two controls is the page which handles the events raised by Control A which calls a method on Control B. You *(well you can hack around to do it)* can't specifically make Control A tell Control B to do something because that creates a direct dependency between the two controls which is bad.

Comment: Can you explain a little more on how to add an event and how to get it raised when control A finishes loading? Should it be in Page Load of ControlA?

Answer (score 1):

This is a fatally-flawed design. You should design your UI so that it doesn't matter in what order the controls load. The order in which controls load is outside of your control.

---

To address "Phill's" issue with an Order/Orderlines control pair:

I assume that the Order control was developed because it's useful by itself. I assume that OrderLines was developed to be able to show the line items for a given order displayed by the Order control.

I contend that there should be a single, composite control which combines Order and OrderLines. this control will pass to the OrderLines control, a DataSource consisting of the line items it is to display. This makes OrderLines independent of any other control - it simply displays the data it is told to display. It has no idea where that data came from.

Note that this can extend to a typical grid / detail / detail lines scenario, where you pass the grid a set of orders; when selected, a particular grid row will pass the Order control the selected order; when its' time to display the line items, pass the line items collection of the current order to the OrderLines control, etc.

This leaves each control with nothing to do but the Single job it is Responsible for.

Comment: There's no reason why controls can't be dependent on other controls.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason to not depend on the order of events firing. If the controls can "depend" on each other even when they can't depend on the order of events, then that's ok. But you can't depend on the order, or even really predict it completely.

Comment: You can, it just becomes procedural code. You don't relie on Page Event's, you relie on your own events raised 1 after another.

Comment: @Phill: that sounds like a severe maintenance problem to me. I would take a lot of convincing. It seems more likely that such a design was by someone who didn't understand event-driven user interfaces and how to write code where the order of events doesn't matter.

Comment: Or it could be that 1 control relies on another control. For example maybe you have an order control and an orderlines control, instead of loading the order in 1 control and the orderlines in the other, you may load them in 1 control and pass the contents to the second control. OH WOW now we have a dependency. I find it funny you're worried about 1 dependency yet theres 1000's of people who can't do SoC with webforms, even MS MVPs are terrible at SoC. And you worry about 1 single dependency on a control that requires some data before it can be loaded.

Comment: @Phill: you're making a number of bad assumptions. I'm not "worried" about it - I've just been there, done that, learned better. In your example, you do not have two controls - you have one. OrderLines makes no sense except when used with Order.

Comment: @John except when used without Order. Assume I used the same control to display the items in my cart when i click the little cart icon. Theres no need to have Order laying around. You may load an Order and pass the OrderItems into the control, but you dont have the Order control. It really depends on what you're trying to achieve. The control still has a single reposibility, it deals with the OrderLines being displayed on the UI. It's dependency is that it must be given the Orderlines. Theres no need for a page lifecycle in the orderlines control.

Comment: @Phill: so, my answer still stands: give the OrderLines control a set of line items to display - it will not have a dependency on any other control - only on its data.

Comment: Which is what my example code does. Instead of loading the Order in the Page. It loads it in the first control. Raises an event on the page, the page calls the load on the second control, passing in the orderlines. OR the second control could be used independently by loading the orderlines in the page and passing them into the control. IF the original poster takes this concept and makes a mess, it's out of my control, but my answer still stands, you can have 1 control dependent on another control, control 1 says its done by telling the page it's done which tells control 2  to do its thing.

Comment: The only way I would agree with you is if control 2 had a direct dependency on control 1. Where control 1 talks directly to control 2 in order for control 2 to work.

Comment: @Phill: do you notice how controls like the DataGrid work? They have DataSource/DataMember properties. Yours shouldn't be as general as that, but still, give the OrderDetails a DataSource property of type `IEnumerable<OrderDetail>` or something like that, and let it just render the data it's given. There's no need for all that other stuff. Controls should simply do what they're told to do, and do it as simply as possible. We've got patterns for this already - see how databound controls work.

Comment: We are talking about User Controls, not Server Controls. Displaying of orderlines is not as simple as shoving it in a datagrid. Maybe if your building a shit looking intranet you can shove it in a datagrid, but maybe theres more than a single datagrid involved in handling the orderlines right. But now your trying to derail the discussion from usercontrols to server controls.

Comment: @Phill: you're not making any sense, and the case with user controls is identical to that of server controls.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, the code behind will still run
- Events could be useful

But if your controls have a specific dependency on each other, maybe they should just be a single control?

Answer (score 0):

"I have a UserControl A that has to be loaded first and after that completes loading, I need to load a UserControl B.

I prefer to add both these user controls on the page at compile time (would like to avoid dynamic loading if possible). "

I would suggest using WebFormsMVP: -

http://webformsmvp.com/ 
http://wiki.webformsmvp.com/index.php?title=Main_Page

As well as being a good implementation of Model-View-Presenter, one of the most useful features of this framework is its support for Messaging.

In a nutshell, you create Message Types, and your usercontrols (views) can post messages of whichever type you need to a message bus. Other controls can subscribe to messages of a particular type and the WebFormsMVP framework will ensure they are delivered.

This allows you to handle interaction between usercontrols by messaging publish & subscribe, without worrying about which order they load in.

Your only other option is  to use dynamic control loading because, as others have pointed out, you can't rely on the order in which ASP.NET loads controls into a container.